# Autenticación no funciona js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, bcryptjs

estoy siguiendo un curso de NodeJS, Angular, y MongoDB en el que el proyecto es desarrollar una API de música y estoy en la parte de registros y sesiones, la parte del registro ya quedó hecha y técnicamente funciona, ya que cuando pruebo enviando datos por Postman los datos se cargan en la base de datos, pero cuando quiero usar el login me devuelve todo el tiempo que las credenciales son incorrectas, aunque sean las mismas que puse en el registro.
La contraseña se ingresa y se guarda sólo el hash que se produce con bcrypt, posteriormente se realiza la comparación usando también uno de sus métodos, no sé qué podría estar fallando ya que no tengo mucha práctica con ese módulo

Código global:

```
'use strict'

let bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')
let user = require('../models/user')
```

Código del registro:

```
function saveUser(req, res){

    let usr = new user()
    //se recolectan los datos del cuerpo de la petición
    let param = req.body

    console.log(param)

    usr.name = param.name
    usr.surname = param.surname
    usr.email = param.email
    usr.role = 'ROLE_USER'
    usr.image = 'null'

    //se guarda en bbdd

    if(param.password){

        bcrypt.hash(usr.password, null, null, function(err, hash){

            usr.password = hash

            if (usr.name != null && usr.surname != null && usr.email != null){

                //se guarda en mongo
                usr.save((err, userStored) => {

                    if(err){
                        res.status(500).send({message:'Error al guardar el usuario.'})
                    }else{
                        if(!userStored){
                            res.status(404).send({message:'Ha ocurrido un error'})
                        }else{
                            res.status(200).send({user:userStored})
                        }
                    }

                })


            }else{
                res.status(200).send({message:'Introduce los datos que faltan.'})
            }

        })

    }else{
        res.status(200).send({message:'Introduce la contraseña'})
    }

}
```

Código del login:

```
function loginUser(req, res){

    let param = req.body

    user.findOne({email: param.email}, (err,datos)=>{
    console.log(user)
        if (err){
            res.status(500).send({message:'Error en la petición.'})
        }else{
            if (!datos) {
                res.status(404).send({message:'El usuario no existe'})
            } else {
                bcrypt.compare(param.password, user.password, function(err, check){

                    if(check){
                        if(param.gethash){
                            //devolver un token de jwt
                        }else{
                            res.status(200).send({hola: datos})
                        }
                    }else{
                        res.status(402).send({message:'Credenciales no correctas.'}) //Este es el mensaje que me devuelve todo el tiempo
                    }

                })
            }
        }

    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo pasar todo y usar async/await, se te va a hacer un caos de callbacks sino.
Podrias probar con compareSync de bcrypt:

```
if(bcrypt.compareSync(param.password, user.password){
  ........
 }else{
       throw 'error..'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando encriptas la contraseña, le estas pasando por parametro la variable incorrecta, cambia:

```
bcrypt.hash(usr.password, null, null, function(err, hash){
```

por

```
bcrypt.hash(param.password, null, null, function(err, hash){
```